# Missing JPG image when publishing html5 in Adobe Animate CC

Tags: adobe-animate

when I publish an animated banner ad from Animate CC, the jpg image won't show, but it's not disabled in the project file itself. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How can anyone tell you what you may be doing wrong if you have not bothered to describe what you *are* doing?

Comment: I made an animated web banner in Adobe Animate and I imported pngs and 1 jpg which is the image.. When I publish it as html5 everything is showing and the animation as well except for the image.

Comment: Missing images in html are the result of the image file being either in the wrong location, or not present at that location, or sometimes an incorrect file name.  Have you checked the path the html image source tag is pointing to? And then make sure the image file is in fact saved at that location.

Comment: Another possibility is your html5 export settings. Make sure you have checked the "Export Image Assets" in your Publish settings, and that after export, the image file is actually located in that folder.  Also make sure when you upload to your web server that the image folder containing the images is included.

Comment: More detailed info is available on the Adobe Animate help website here: https://helpx.adobe.com/in/animate/using/creating-publishing-html5-canvas-document.html

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. Apparently, when I name my images as "img" it doesn't show when published. I am pretty new in using Animate and this is  pretty weird to me that you can't name your image "img"

Comment: If this solved the problem, don't forget to choose your own answer as best.